# CD-ROM not detected

Tags: 11.10, files, cd

I am using Ubuntu Oneiric. I tried inserting a CD-ROM containig some files of mine into my laptop but it was neither detected nor auto-mounted. I can assure that my CD is fine since it works on the other OS (Windows-7) on my laptop. How can I view the contents of the CD and access my files?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find the CD/DVD drives available on your Ubuntu system, please use `wodim --devices`, but first check if your cdrom is plugged in or not. The following information is a sample output of `wodim --devices`:

```
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'TSSTcorp' 'CDDVDW SH-S223F'
```

---